# How to fix a scrape in a hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring

Although I put a blanket under a very heavy object to move it, it was so heavy that it gouged a very shallow 3-foot line in the floor.

Is there a DIY way to fill and or buff it out without having to call a floor service?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Let me ask you this: if you get the line wet, with a dropper or sopping rag, does it almost disappear in a few seconds?

Comment: [Wood flooring scratched](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182142/wood-flooring-scratched) | [How to fix drag marks on wooden floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107660/how-to-fix-drag-marks-on-wooden-floor)

Answer (score 2):

- First, clean the floor to remove the black marks and any dirt.
- Quick and dirty: Some wood floor waxes, without other preparation, might hide the scratch. Test in a hidden area and let dry before doing the whole floor.
- There are wood touch-up pens, such as [these from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wood%20touch%20up%20pen), that can be used to make the scratch less apparent.

  - Carefully test a few of the pens in a hidden area.
  - The eye is good at seeing linear features, so use different pens to match the color of the wood on either side -- using one color will just leave a mark only slightly less apparent than the original.
  - Follow up with floor wax to restore gloss.
- If the finish is *solvent based* lacquer, then test, in an obscure area, if a common solvent such as acetone or xylene dissolves enough of the surrounding finish to smooth over the scratch. *Use caution! These are flammable and somewhat toxic.* Again, it may be difficult to blend the repair so as not to leave a streak.